# dhtml calendar not triggering in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dhtml

I'm using [jcal2](http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/) calendar for choosing date from calender. It working when i'm using

```
<input type="text" id="txtDob" >&nbsp;<img
                src="images/Calendar.png" width="25" height="22" id="f_btn1" />

            <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
                                            Calendar.setup({
                                                inputField :"txtDob",trigger:"f_btn1",onSelect:function(){this.hide()},showTime:12,dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"
                                            });//]]>
            </script>
```

But, not working in this case

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDob" Enabled="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;<img
                src="images/Calendar.png" width="25" height="22" id="f_btn1" />

            <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
                                            Calendar.setup({
                                                inputField :"txtDob",trigger:"f_btn1",onSelect:function(){this.hide()},showTime:12,dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"
                                            });//]]>
            </script>
```

Need help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing Server Id of `<asp:TextBox>` control. You should use Client ID in your javascript.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDob" Enabled="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;<img
                src="images/Calendar.png" width="25" height="22" id="f_btn1" />    
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
                Calendar.setup({
                         inputField :"<%= txtDob.ClientID %>", 
                         trigger:"f_btn1",onSelect:function(){this.hide()},showTime:12,dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y"
                              });//]]>
</script>
```